# Как оперативно подключать самые актуальные сторонние библиотеки

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

В каждый новый проект приходится вручную качать сторонние библиотеки(javascript, jquery, font-awesome и проч.) и подключать их в html-файле. Есть ли автоматизированные способы сделать это? И также возможность автоматически контролировать самые актуальные версии библиотек?

Comment: Вкратце да - есть. Это называется пакетный менеджер, самый популярный в экосистеме javascript - npm (https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/what-is-npm). Но на практике оно обычно несколько сложнее чем Вы описываете)

Comment: Я так понимаю, что используя npm мы закачиваем пакет определенной библиотеки, и далее, при помощи gulp задаем таски на обновление или закачку в проект для подключения на странице уже из  директории проекта

Comment: Нуууу например так. Но у меня например не так. Если б я хотел полноценно расписывать, то написал бы ответ) Главное понимать что за выкачку и контроль внешних зависимостей отвечает npm. Что делать с файлами из npm и как их добавить к проекту - зависит от того как у вас устроено и что у вас там вертится, вебпак, browserify, зоопарк галп плагинов или еще что-то. Еще один момент - Вы врядли хотите самые актуальные версии сторонних библиотек автоматически, иначе ваш проект будет очень часто ломаться.

Comment: короче говоря, собрать, настроить и отладить конструктор. Спасибо за подсказку.

Answer (score 0):

Например последнюю версию jQuery можно подключить следующим образом

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

И у вас всегда будет последняя версия, на счет остального не подскажу.